# Any way to automatically mark sharps where edges of UV maps are?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have a photoscanned object that (of course has randomly marked edges of the UVs) and placed them in the correct places on the material (right window). Is there a way to automatically select all the edges where the UV edges are so that I can then mark them as "Sharps"?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blender can mark the edges for you :).

1. Select your whole UV map an go *UV > Seams From Islands*
2. Select one of the new seams and go *Select Similar > Seams*
3. Go *Edge > Mark Sharp*

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!